# How to get count(id) from table with graphql

Tags: graphql

I've been playing around with resolvers in graphql and need what's seemingly a simple query, but I can't figure it out.

I want to query a table and get results in something like this:

```
SELECT hero_id, count(id) FROM "Build" 
GROUP BY hero_id
ORDER BY hero_id
```

How do I write the resolver to return the count of rows by id on a table?

I thought the Table.findAndCountAll() would return results I'm looking for.

```
const buildCount = {


type: BuildCountType,

  resolve(parent, args){
    return Build.findAndCountAll().then(result => {
      console.log(result)
      return {
        count: result.rows
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Thanks,

StuckAndConfused ;)

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand. Can you maybe add more code? In GraphQL the _shape of the field resolver result_ needs to match the _shape of the field type_. Could you for example add the `BuildCountType`? What framework/library is `Table.findAndCountAll()` from? What is `console.log(result)` logging to the console?

Comment: Can you share your type definition for BuiltCountType and as asked before, what does the console.log show?